# 'Anglican' Tag Synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I propose making [church-of-england](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-of-england) and [episcopal](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episcopal) synonyms of [anglicanism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglicanism).

Comment: Definitely! episcopal too.

Comment: @curiousdannii added [tag:episcopal]

Comment: The American Episcopal Church and the English Anglican Church are in communion, so it makes sense that they are part of the *same denomination*.

Comment: @Anonymous though that may not always be the case... there are now parallel Anglican denominations that aren't in communion. See [the FCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fellowship_of_Confessing_Anglicans)

Comment: @curiousdannii but few of the Lutheran denominations are in communion (if any), and we only have one [tag:lutheranism] tag. I'm fine either way, but the current pattern seem to *not* have separate tags for every denomination, just for overarching theological traditions.

Comment: @Daи yeah I don't disagree. Both the Anglican Communion and the FCA are Anglican and both fit into Anglicanism.

Comment: There's a difference between *episcopal* and *Episcopalian*. The Roman Catholic Church is episcopal.

Comment: @AndrewLeach that is true, but the current tag definition for [tag:episcopal] is "Protestant Episcopal Church representing the Anglican communion in the United States." That should be changed and questions properly tagged if that's the definition we're going to use.

Comment: Yes. What is currently "episcopal" should be renamed "episcopalian".

Comment: I can get behind that, but should Episcopalian then also be a synonym of Anglican or vice versa?

Comment: Given that we speak of "the Anglican communion", with the Episcopal Church as a member of that communion, I'd say Episcopalian should be the synonym and Anglican the primary term.

Comment: May be church of england belongs to older england church too, when it was in communion with Roman Church, and other orthodox churches (before 1054).

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ That distinction isn't usually made, and if it is, then the pre-Reformation Church in England is usually called the "Church in England" precisely to distinguish from the Church of England established by statute.

Answer (score 4):

**Anglicanism** is a church tradition, just like Presbyterianism and Baptist. The Church of England and the Episcopalian church are national denominations in the Anglican tradition. In general we don't use tags for individual denominations, so I think they should be merged into [anglicanism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglicanism).

**Episcopal** technically means a church with bishops, but the only question tagged with it is about the Episcopalian church, so it's more of a tag typo. As there is already a tag for [bishops](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bishops) we don't need to keep it.